# looking for an equivalent of Tensorflow normalization layer in Pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I was using ['tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization'](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Normalization). This layer is cool since you can save weights in this layer to normalize any input data to this layer.
However, I couldn't find [any normalization layer in Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#normalization-layers).
Is there a layer that functions the same role?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in that achieves this is PyTorch. However, you can measure the mean and standard deviation yourself (keeping only the relevant axes), then use [`torchvision.transform.Normalize`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize) with those statistics.

For instance in order to measure [`mean`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mean.html#torch-mean) and [`std`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.std.html#torch-std) over the channels:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(16, 3, 10, 10)
>>> mean, std = x.mean((0, 2, 3)), x.std((0, 2, 3))
(tensor(0.4941), tensor(0.2899))
```

Then initialize a transform:

```
>>> t = torchvision.transform.Normalize(mean, std)
```

You can use this function on a new dataset to normalize it based on the initial dataset's statistics:

```
>>> z_normalized = t(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you spent about 1 sec looking for it :-) In pytorch, it is done through the transformations.

For example:

```
from torchvision import transforms

transforms.Normalize(
    mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
    std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
)
```

There are literally thousands of examples over there on the internet.

Comment: *"[tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization] will coerce its inputs into a distribution centered around 0 with standard deviation 1 [...] by precomputing the mean and variance of the data"* cf. documentation: which is not what `torchvision.transforms.Normalize` does.

Comment: You state that this is incorrect somehow but you *literally* gave the same answer.

Comment: It is not exactly what OP asks: `torchvision.Normalize` does not measure statistics. You haven't shown how to use `Normalize` in order to replicate `tf`'s implementation of `Normalization`.